# How to use facebook publish stream method in a '.js' file

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using bellow code which is in a '.php' file, to publish stream.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      FB.init( 
      {
        appId  : 'MY_APP_ID',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      var publish = {
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message: '',
        picture : 'http://www.associationregion.org/images/stories/slides/Upload.png',
        link : 'http://apps.facebook.com/puzzlegts/',
        name: 'Go to image',
        caption: 'taged you in a photo',
        description: 'test 2',
        actions : { name : 'Go to app', link : 'http://apps.facebook.com/puzzlegts/'}
        };
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {alert("posted");});

    </script>
```

Now I have a javascript file named 'publish.js' and I want to add publish stream method to a function in my 'publish.js' file. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?
**Problem arise since I can't use '`<script>`' tag in a '.js' file.Therefore I can't include bellow code.**

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Or can anyone please post the suitable code for a '.js' file

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your page

```
<script src="publish.js"></script>
```

and add this to your publish.js

```
  FB.init( 
  {
    appId  : '266000346762008',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  var publish = {
    method: 'stream.publish',
    message: '',
    picture : 'http://www.associationregion.org/images/stories/slides/Upload.png',
    link : 'http://apps.facebook.com/puzzlegts/',
    name: 'Go to image',
    caption: 'taged you in a photo',
    description: 'test 2',
    actions : { name : 'Go to app', link : 'http://apps.facebook.com/puzzlegts/'}
    };
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {alert("posted");});
```

(without script tags)

Comment: Where do I have to add <script src="publish.js"></script>? I have only publish.js file

Comment: after your facebook implemention (first <script

Comment: I didn't get your answer. I have only 'publish.js' file. As I know I can't use <script> tag in a '.js' file

Comment: ah.no, you can't. create .html file and put there `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script><script src="publish.js"></script>`

Comment: OK. I have another question. Do I have to put above publishing method inside a javescript function? Seems like it doesn't work without a function

Comment: @Roshanck: you don't. but the main is to put these script tags in positions as it is in my comment

Answer (score 0):

You have add it programmatically then or just use the [asynchronous loading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'MY_APP_ID',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    var publish = {
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message: '',
        picture : 'http://www.associationregion.org/images/stories/slides/Upload.png',
        link : 'http://apps.facebook.com/puzzlegts/',
        name: 'Go to image',
        caption: 'taged you in a photo',
        description: 'test 2',
        actions : { name : 'Go to app', link : 'http://apps.facebook.com/puzzlegts/'}
    };
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {alert("posted");});
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Notes:

- You need to insure that you have the `fb-root` div is in your markup
- this will only fire once the library `all.js` is fully loaded

Comment: "You need to insure that you have the fb-root div is in your markup". What do you mean by that? How can I do that?

Comment: The above will be in your js file but you should have `<div id="fb-root"></div>` somewhere in your `<body>` tag

Comment: OK. I added it. And now it display 'posted' alert message. But in my wall I can't see any posted wall message

Comment: You are aware that the above code "alone" won't post anything right? you need to make sure the user is connected to your app also the response may contain an error! so the callback is not always a success!

Comment: Check this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) to see how you should handle the callback properly and this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to login the user. For this to work you need to add `oauth: true` to your `FB.init()` function and add the `publish_stream` to the `scope` parameter in `FB.login()`

Comment: User is fully authenticate and has the publish stream permission to the app

Comment: Then check what's in the response and act accordingly.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check what is in the response? I put this inside the alert. 'alert(response)' and it gives me '[object Object]'

Comment: You can check it [here](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/4834da858f483667dd280f620e95c779) OR you can use the [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/)