# How to publish on Facebook in instagram way

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing an application which is supposed to publish on Facebook.

I am following parameters defined in [How to use facebook publish stream method in a '.js' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242506/how-to-use-facebook-publish-stream-method-in-a-js-file)

However this leads to posting as url link:

[image]

I would rather like to achieve something like instagram is using:

[image]

Specifically, I would like to achieve the "Barbara likes 10 photos on Instagram", where the photos link directly to instagram pages. I can't find any definition of how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Facebook Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) 
for achieving this, this will give a custom way to implement your story.
you can go through [this](http://facebook.w3villa.com/post.html) link for a quick tutorial. Instagram is also using open graph 
 for this story.

Comment: I would be happy, if you knew answer for my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126496/how-facebook-stories-decide-how-to-show-images